# Haml: link_to vs button_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, button, hyperlink, haml

From what I understand, `link_to` is used for get methods, and `button_to` is used for post methods.

On the other hand, I was told that with HTML5 semantics, `<button>` is used for any type of clickable...well, button. In the case I have a clickable button that sends a user to a form to fill out, should I create a `button_to` or a `link_to`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's simpler that you think.
That methods are Rails helpers and don't have anything to do with haml.
Yes, one method is for get and another for post methods. If you need to post any data to controller, use `button_to` (for example when deleting a record). Otherwise, `link_to` is enough.

Moreover, you can make `link_to` posting data using `:method` parameter:

```
= link_to "Something", some_path, :method => :post
```

Answering your question, use `link_to`.

Comment: this adds `method: 'post'` not `data-method: 'post'` to the link

Answer (score 4):

The main principle difference between the [`#link_to`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to), and [`#button_to`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/button_to) is that the `#link_to` just creates a link tag `A`, and makes simple AJAX request without an additional data, while `#button_to` creates a `FORM` with a custom data, so the form can be used to make extended AJAX request to a webserver. The form data includes embedded CSRF-token, which is used to authentication the request. In case of `#link_to` CSRF-token must be serualized and send in `on_click` event.

Answer (score 3):

You **should** use links to point the user to a resource, like an article.

But you **have to tend to use** buttons to point to an action(like "Create"/"Send" on your edit page). If this doesn't agree with your interface -- style them like as a link.

Here's why: **you cannot** point your user to any non-GET action via `link_to` if he lacks the javascript support. So, buttons are the only options to make your send/destroy action to be triggered in this case.

Feel free to use **both approaches** if your link points to a page that eventually leads to a modification of a resource (link/button to an edit/create page that shows a form), like in your case.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to simply send a user to somewhere, it is get request. So you should use link_to in this case. By the way, you can use the link_to for post requests and other requests (like button_to too) if you will specify :method. For example: `=link_to "some path", some_path, :method => :get`

Answer (score 1):

**Updated for rails 7**

Making a post request from a link:

`link_to` method:

```
<%= link_to "Add to cart", line_items_path(product.id), data: {turbo_method: :post} %>
```

`button_to` method:

```
<%= button_to "Add to cart", line_items_path(product.id) %>
```