# button_to in form tag

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I am developing a website and I have this problem.

I want to browse another page if a button is clicked.

In localhost:3000/articles/browse page

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-left" >
  <%= link_to comments_path %>
</form>
```

This works properly to browse comment page but

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
  <%= button_to comments_path %>
</form>
```

This does not direct to comments_path.

And why this was happened?

I have solved my self.

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-left" action=<%= comments_path %>>
  <button name="abc">
</form>
```

> And the result is that `button_to`
>   should not used in a `form` tag!!

Is there anyone who can answer why this happens?

Comment: Other questions don't work in my case. button_to browse articles/browse again!!!

Comment: I edited the question in detail and the solution does not exist. Could you reopen my question and make it as 'not duplicate'?

Comment: Your answer form is deleted because of some reason!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<%= button_to "Comments", comments_path%>
```

Regarding your second question, as said by @Clonex duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10374322/haml-link-to-vs-button-to).

Comment: I have solved my self.                                                                             
     <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" action = <%= comments_path %>>
          <button name="abc"> 
    </form>

Comment: Your solution is not right and I edited your answer as I solved and I think this  will help lots of people.

Comment: @LucasH Thanks for your feedback.